# Problema en PASCAL, no informa lo que debería

Tags: condiciones, pascal, else

estoy haciendo unos ejercicios en pascal, dice así:

> programa que lea el número de legajo y el promedio de cada alumno de la
>   facultad. La lectura finaliza cuando se ingresa el legajo -1, que no debe procesarse. Al finalizar la lectura, informar:
>
> a. La cantidad de alumnos leída
>   b. La cantidad de alumnos cuyo promedio supera 6.5

Yo hice esto ya:

```
program eje6;
var
legajo, total:Integer;
promedio,m6:Real;

begin
Read(legajo);
Read(promedio);
total:=total+1;
while legajo > -1 do
begin
  if promedio > 6 then
   begin
     Read(legajo,promedio);
     m6:=m6+1;
     total:=total+1;
   end;
  if promedio < 5 then
    begin
      Read(legajo,promedio);
      total:=total+1;
    end;
end;
WriteLn('alumnos leidos ',total-1);
WriteLn('mas de 6: ', m6)
end.
```

esto no informa, no suma, y despues del "-1" que sería el "legajo" tengo que poner el "promedio" lo tenia resuelto un poco, pero lo empecé de 0 y tengo eso.

Comment: Que es lo que esta mostrando, y que deberia mostrar? a pesar de que la logica parece bastante complicada, a simple vista hace lo que vos queres.

Comment: Ya he perdido todo conocimiento de pascal, pero no deberías inicializar `total` en primer lugar ? Ej: `total:=1`

Comment: No calcula bien el valor de promedio de mas de 6.5(yo puse 6 para no complicarme) y el total, no suma todo, si es menor a 6 o mayor, sobre lo de inicializar `total` aca no afecta creo, me suma de 0 como tendria que ser si la inicializo

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias cosas a comentar...

Si en un `if` y en un `else` (el segundo `if` debería serlo) tienes el mismo codigo, debes sacarlo fuera.

```
if promedio > 6 then begin  
  Read(legajo,promedio);   
  m6:=m6+1;    
  total:=total+1;   
end;   
if promedio < 5 then   
begin      
  Read(legajo,promedio);    
  total:=total+1;    
end;
```

Al sacar las líneas iguales fuera, el `else` te queda vacío y por lo tanto es inútil:

```
Read(legajo,promedio);
total:=total+1;
if promedio > 6 then
begin
  m6:=m6+1;    
end;
```

Si lees los 2 números en el mismo `Read` estás obligando a leer los 2 para saber si el **legajo** es -1, por lo tanto es mejor que los leas por separado.

```
Read(legajo);
Read(promedio);
```

Para acceder al `while` la condición es sólo sobre el valor de **legajo**, por lo tanto la lectura del primer **promedio** la puesdes dejar dentro:

```
  Read(legajo);
  while legajo > -1 do begin
    total := total + 1;
    Read(promedio);
    if promedio > 6.5 then
```

Si cambias estas cosas el programa funciona correctamente según  lo que yo he entendido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, lo estoy intentando armar con las cosas que me pasas,te pero veo que me quedan sueltas, por ejemplo `Read(legajo);
Read(promedio);` y `  Read(legajo);
  while legajo > -1 do begin
    total := total + 1;
    Read(promedio);
    if promedio > 6.5 then`

Comment: Puedes agregar al final como te quedó, porque lo edite, pero aún así no me funciona, así la marco como "respondida" la respuesta